# Is it possible to run 2 loop functions without one of them not getting reached at all?

Tags: python, kivy, py-telegram-bot-api

I am new to this, i am using both kivy and pyTelegramBotApi to run a bot and a window that controls part of the bot in one script (i tried using 2 but i got the same problem :P)

At the end of the script you need to add `bot.polling()` for the telegram bot to check new messages and `App().run()` to run the kivy app

The problem is that these two functions make the script loop, so when one of them runs it loops and the other never gets to run

```
#end of the script
bot.polling() #Bot can check new messages and will loop
TestApp().run() #Because bot looped the script, this part is never reached, it happens the same thing if i put this first, but bot.polling() wont run
```

is there a way to run both stuff in some way?

i tried to use asyncio in this way (i am not sure if asyncio is the indicated way to do this):

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(bot.polling())
loop.create_task(App().run())
loop.run_forever() #or  run_until_complete()
```

but the second one (in this case `App().run()`) never runs, any ideas?

Comment: I don't now anything about asyncio, I'd just use the `threading` library where you can just type `thread1 = Thread(target=bot.polling) thread1.start()` and repeat for the other task

Comment: Don't use the `Thread` to start the `TestApp().run()`. That must be run on the main thread. Use the `Thread` for the `bot.polling`, and  then just run `TestApp().run()` as is.

Comment: Thank you 2 so much! it works! now when i close the windows it freezes haha but i guess its another issue i will have to fix :P